# PHP in Edit Post link

Tags: php

What is the best way to add php to the edit link?

For example: insert `<?php echo of_get_option('dappo_actionbtncolor', 'dappblue' ); ?>` into the span tag of `<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit this', 'mytheme' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use `get_edit_post_link()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_edit_post_link)), which returns *just* the link, allowing you to use it however you need, according to your purposes.